# animation of a graph of an equation javascript

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, chart.js

I'm stuck on this issue and don't know where to put my hands.
I have to draw in javascript the animation of the graph of the equation `y = x ^ 3`

**what do i mean?**

knowing y (*for example y = 10*) I would like the graph to start from (0; 0) up to (x; 10) following the equation `y = x ^ 3`
also I would like to create a button which can be clicked during the animation and tells me what y is the graph at **that precise moment**

for now thanks to chart.js i managed to do this:

JS

```
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
   var data = {
   labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   datasets: [
       {
      
           function: function(x) { return x*x*x },
           borderColor: "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
           data: [],
           fill: true
       }]
    };

Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
        var data = chart.config.data;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data.labels.length; j++) {
                var fct = data.datasets[i].function,
                    x = data.labels[j],
                    y = fct(x);
                data.datasets[i].data.push(y);
            }
        }
    }
});

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

result

[image: result]

for now I only have the graph, there is no animation and I cannot select the maximum y

**how can I do?**

Answer (score 0):

To set max amount on your y Axes you can use the `max` property or `suggestedMax` if you want to make sure that if the data goes bigger the axis adapts. For the animation you can write custom logic as in the example underneath. I only dont know how to get the value its at on the click:

```js
const labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

const totalDuration = 5000;
const delayBetweenPoints = totalDuration / labels.length;
const previousY = (ctx) => ctx.index === 0 ? ctx.chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(100) : ctx.chart.getDatasetMeta(ctx.datasetIndex).data[ctx.index - 1].getProps(['y'], true).y;

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [],
      borderWidth: 1,
      function: function(x) {
        return x * x * x
      },
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        max: 250
      }
    },
    animation: {
      x: {
        type: 'number',
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: delayBetweenPoints,
        from: NaN, // the point is initially skipped
        delay(ctx) {
          if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.xStarted) {
            return 0;
          }
          ctx.xStarted = true;
          return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
        }
      },
      y: {
        type: 'number',
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: delayBetweenPoints,
        from: previousY,
        delay(ctx) {
          if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.yStarted) {
            return 0;
          }
          ctx.yStarted = true;
          return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'data',
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
      var data = chart.config.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.labels.length; j++) {
          var fct = data.datasets[i].function,
            x = data.labels[j],
            y = fct(x);
          data.datasets[i].data.push(y);
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.1/chart.js" integrity="sha512-HJ+fjW1Hyzl79N1FHXTVgXGost+3N5d1i3rr6URACJItm5CjhEVy2UWlNNmFPHgX94k1RMrGACdmGgVi0vptrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you! there is a way to make sure that if the data goes bigger only the x adapts and the y stay?

Comment: Should be doing that already if I understand you correctly, try increasing labels array (cooking ATM so can't check)

Comment: it's a bit difficult to explain the y chosen by me must not be the end of the graph, I would like the animation to stop at that point, and above the point there must be unused space like the graph in this video youtube.com/watch?v=w48ahDZQPnQ