# graph of an equation animated javascript (crash game)

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chart.js

i don't know how to get out of this problem

I have the animation of the graph of the equation `y = x ^ 2`

this:

```js
const labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

const totalDuration = 2000;
const delayBetweenPoints = totalDuration / labels.length;
const previousY = (ctx) => ctx.index === 0 ? ctx.chart.scales.y.getPixelForValue(100) : ctx.chart.getDatasetMeta(ctx.datasetIndex).data[ctx.index - 1].getProps(['y'], true).y;

var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [],
      borderWidth: 1,
      function: function(x) {
        return x * x 
      },
    borderColor: "rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)",
        fill: true
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        max: 200
      },
      x: {
        suggestedMax: 210
      }
    },
    animation: {
      x: {
        type: 'number',
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: delayBetweenPoints,
        from: NaN, // the point is initially skipped
        delay(ctx) {
          if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.xStarted) {
            return 0;
          }
          ctx.xStarted = true;
          return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
        }
      },
      y: {
        type: 'number',
        easing: 'linear',
        duration: delayBetweenPoints,
        from: previousY,
        delay(ctx) {
          if (ctx.type !== 'data' || ctx.yStarted) {
            return 0;
          }
          ctx.yStarted = true;
          return ctx.index * delayBetweenPoints;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [{
    id: 'data',
    beforeInit: function(chart) {
      var data = chart.config.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.labels.length; j++) {
          var fct = data.datasets[i].function,
            x = data.labels[j],
            y = fct(x);
          data.datasets[i].data.push(y);
        }
      }
    }
  }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.1/chart.js" integrity="sha512-HJ+fjW1Hyzl79N1FHXTVgXGost+3N5d1i3rr6URACJItm5CjhEVy2UWlNNmFPHgX94k1RMrGACdmGgVi0vptrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

I have to add 3 things and I don't know how to get out of it

1. how can I define a **Y** value for which the line stops going up?
2. if this **Y** is bigger than the axis data, how can they **adapt**?
3. how can I create a button which when clicked tells me the **exact Y** value at **that moment** during the animation?

I wish something like this graph would come out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w48ahDZQPnQ

Comment: Does this answer your question? [animation of a graph of an equation javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66942295/animation-of-a-graph-of-an-equation-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the Y max value like this in your code to auto adjust Y axis scale.

```
beforeInit: function(chart) {
  var data = chart.config.data;
  let maxValue = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.datasets.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data.labels.length; j++) {
      var fct = data.datasets[i].function,
        x = data.labels[j],
        y = fct(x);
        if (maxValue < y) {
          maxValue = y;
        }
      data.datasets[i].data.push(y);
    }
  }
  chart.options.scales.y.max = maxValue;
}
```